# match text from two a-links and change the class of the first

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I want to fire a style if these the content of `.firstA` and `.secondA` contain the same text.
I thought this code would do it, alas, it didn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<tr>
<td><a id="a11" href="#" class="firstA">text</a><a id="c10" href="#" class="secondA">text</a></td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$('.firstA').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == $(this).next('.secondA').text()){
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }
});
```

PS: the .secondA is hidden witha `$(.secondA).hide();` function, could this be the problem?

Comment: Looks correct. Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: The code you posted works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/aHPfc/1/

Comment: So could it be the "hidden" that does it?

Comment: Nah, the `display` property value should not affect the text content. I added to the fiddle above. Try copying more of your actual code until you can reproduce the issue in a fiddle, the error is probably somewhere else.